# Can't run jar file created from Maven Shade Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-shade-plugin

When I try to run the jar file nothing happens. I also get no errors when I try to run it through command using

```
java -jar ".\target\DApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar"
```

My main is located here:

.\target\DApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar\com\q\maven\DApi\GUI.class

I can also see all the folders for the dependencies I am using when I open the jar. I've tried using other ways to build it through Eclipse but I still am getting the same issue of nothing happening when I run it. The project runs fine inside of Eclipse.

The following is my build in the pom file:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>com.q.maven.DApi.GUI</mainClass>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
          <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

My main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GUI window = new GUI();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the output of executing the command?

Comment: Just a blank line.

Comment: Sounds like it might be executing successfully if there is no error exit code. You may need to show us your main method.

Comment: I added my main it to the question. It initializes a JFrame.

Comment: If you put a System.out.println in your main method does it print?

Comment: Does your program run if the JAR is on your classpath?
`java -cp ".\target\DApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar" com.q.maven.DApi.GUI`